# Close all inherited fds at program start

Tags: c++, linux, fork, file-descriptor, child-process

My C++ program, ran under Linux, runs a lot of child processes, and after each `fork` to run a child process, I close all inherited fds to prevent children from accessing them. Now, my program inherits some fds from its parent as well, and it would make much more sense to just close all those inherited fds at program start, than to close them over and over again after each `fork`.

Problem is, I don't really know which fds are actually inherited, and which are mine. When I'm at `main()`, a lot of code has already run, and the program might have already created some of its own fds (e.g. during initialization of libraries, static objects etc). So how could I close just the inherited fds?

Comment: You do not have 'yours' or 'foreigner' descriptors. When app is forked, everything is copied. The two copies are indistinguishable other than by return code of fork().

Comment: I am well aware of that

Comment: Prepare some kind of simple stub that closes all file descriptors and then executes your "final" program.

Comment: @dragonroot, if you are aware of this, you should know that what you are trying to do is not possible.

Comment: One possible solution is to use some mechanism to run the code which would close all fds ahead of all other initialization code in the program. I'm not aware of such mechanism, but it might exist. In any case, I disagree that what I'm asking is impossible by definition

Comment: That's basically what @nsilent22 was suggesting. If you create a stub program that runs between the top-level parent creating the file descriptors and the start of your program, you can identify all the open file descriptors and do whatever you need to do with them.

Comment: But why would you care about such file descriptors. If there is a bug, it is in the program doing exec without dealing with file descriptors it should not let you keep. Chances are you just want to set O_CLOEXEC on them and be done with it.

Comment: Hmm. Setting O_CLOEXEC on all existing file descriptors at program start instead of closing them is actually a great idea! Thanks! The reason to do this is simply performance - so I don't have to close a whole bunch of file descriptors every time I fork

Answer (score 0):

1. It's not clear from your question: do you just call fork() or you additinally call execve() after fork()? 
   If execve() is called, O_CLOEXEC flag should help you. You can set this flag on descriptors you aren't going to keep after execve(), via fcntl() syscall or by passing O_CLOEXEC to the syscall that creates your fds.
2. If you don't call execve(), you will totally inherit parent's state. If the file descriptor is 'yours' therefore it have been stored somewhere in your data structures. So you can iterate these structures and handle descriptors corresponding to your needs.